# tweaking a regex in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

I need to create a regex for Notepad++ for the below expression, when the text of "Letter to Mary"changes

```
{\par\pard\qc \b Letter to Mary °\par\pard}
```

I tried the following but it is not working

```
\{\\par\\pard\\qc \\b ([^}]+)\\pard}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I need to create a regex for Notepad++ for the below expression

```
{\par\pard\qc \b Letter to Mary °\par\pard}
```

- Menu "Search" > "Find" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `\{\\par\\pard\\qc \\b (.*?)\\pard\}`

  `(.*?)` will match `Letter to Mary °`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Find Next"

  [image]

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)